# WKWebView is cutting off my other view in Xcode 9 & Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, wkwebview

I'm very new to working with Xcode and Swift.

I've run into a problem with working on the new WKWebView.  I normally use the storyboard, but I learned there is a bug with Xcode 9 that will not allow you to use the WKWebView if you doing a build that includes anything before ios 11.  I've learned it is possible if you add it programmatically however and have been following Apple's instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

I need to be able to add the Webview, while allowing space at the top for a custom view I created that is acting as a banner.  This top view has a height of 116 and the constraints are working on all devices and orientation before adding the Webview.

When I add the Webview and add it's custom size and constraints, the webview works perfectly also on all devices and orientations.  However, my top banner view is missing.

I'm not sure what I'm missing or if I wrote the code wrong for the Webview.  I'll attach screenshots and the code to the Webview.

Thank you so much for the help!

[This is the Webview tab that is missing the banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1rik.png)

[This is another tab that shows what the banner looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/202BB.png)

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {


var myWebView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    myWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    myWebView.uiDelegate = self
    view = myWebView

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 116, width: 414, height: 571), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration() )
    self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
    myWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    myWebView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 116).isActive = true
    myWebView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 49).isActive = true
    myWebView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myWebView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myWebView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 414).isActive = true
    myWebView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 571).isActive = true


    let myURL = URL(string: "https://apple.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    myWebView.load(myRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your banner disappears just because you put your instance of WKWebView into `view` property of ViewController, in the last line of `loadView` method. Try to add it as subview, or even create 2 views in Interface Builder, first for your banner and second for the web view, you also will be able to set constraints via IB.

Answer (score 0):

Remove width and height constraints as long as your are setting Leading , Trailing , Top and Bottom constraints , also bottom should -49 instead of 49 as webViewBottom = mainviewBottom - 49

```
  myWebView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 116).isActive = true
  myWebView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -49).isActive = true
  myWebView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
  myWebView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```